# sloped asymptote

Tags: calculus

A well-behaved (continuous, mostly differentiable) function $f:B\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ will have an asymptote $A(x)=kx+d$ with slope $k$ on the right iff
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=k
$$
Therefore, the function $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}+x$, whose derivative is $f'(x)=\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}+1$ (which goes to 1 as $x\rightarrow\infty$), has a sloped asymptote $A(x)=x+d$. To find $d$, I set
$$
0=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(f(x)-A(x)\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(x^{\frac{2}{3}}-d\right)
$$
but the expression on the right will clearly not be zero for any $d\in\mathbb{R}$. Is there a sloped asymptote in this case; and if yes, what is its $y$-intercept? If not, how does this square with $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=1$?

Comment: I think you wanted $f(x)-kx$ not $f(x)-A(x)$ in the argument of the limit.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to \infty}{(f(x)-kx-d)}=0\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to \infty}{(f(x)-kx)}=d, k=\lim_{x\to \infty}{f\prime(x)}$$

First you determine k then you determine d.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your premise, namely that a function will have a linear asymptote when its derivative has a finite limit, is incorrect.  You already have a counterexample.  Another counterexample is $f(x)=\log x$ whose derivative's limit is zero but clearly lacks a horizontal asymptote.

Instead, we say functions $f,g$ are *asymptotically equivalent* iff $\lim_{x\to\infty} {f(x)\over g(x)}=1$.

Comment: Dang. I've been assuming this for a long time. When you look at the function graph of x^(2/3)+x in desmos and zoom out, it also sure looks like there is an asymptote! But you are clearly right; just goes to show how slowly some of these functions make their way to infinity!

Comment: Yep.  I would also add *asymptotic equivalence* is a bit weaker than the notion of having a sloped asymptote that you propose in that if $\liminf_{x\to\infty}g(x)>0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x)-g(x))=0,$ then $f,g$ are asymptotically equivalent, but the reverse implication does not hold.  So while $f(x)=x^{2/3}+x$ does not have a linear asymptote, it is *asymptotically equivalent* to $g(x)=x$.